# iOS Widget data sharing is stopped when widget updations done

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, widget, appgroups

I created today extension widget,and created shared data base using Appgroups i am able to retrieve data from sqlite,whatever change i am doing in app its resembling widget too so no problem unto here, but when i update any thing  in widget , its not reflecting in app when i debug it is updating db but its not reflecting in app and after that app updatations also not reflecting in widget.

i am using this container url for App Groups:
return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"######"];

Comment: What is the sqlite tag for?

Comment: I m using sqlitedb to store the data